# Can Zoom cloud recordings associated with a recurring meeting be shared automatically with particiapants?

Tags: zoom-sdk

I have several Zoom meetings which I record and store in the cloud. Is there a way to specify email addresses to automatically share these recordings with?

It's getting old doing this manually, especially considering that I am paying almost $150/yr for this software...

I looked through the meeting recording sharing settings in the client and this [doc](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/205347605-Managing-and-sharing-cloud-recordings#h_750e7e94-45e4-415b-a67a-ac8b49e74fa2), but no dice.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Create an app on zoom marketplace and you have to write a script using any programming language you like to integrate your zoom app to download the meeting recording and send it to whatever email you want it to send.